# How to save compilation progress using Bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am building tensorflow from source using bazel, within a docker container, and it seems that the progress of the compilation is stored in cache temporarily. This means that if I make a change and recompile, only the modules that are dependent to the change will be rebuilt.

Is it possible to store the compilation progress in a more permanent location, so that the progress gets saved?

I tried using the --disk_cache flag in order to supply a local directory as a cache location, but when I recompiled, everything was compiled from scratch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`--disk_cache` is the right way to set a cache. It sounds like the code and environment you're using doesn't get cache hits where you're expecting. There's some documentation on [debugging cache hits with local execution](https://bazel.build/remote/cache-local) (`--disk_cache` uses the same infrastructure as a truly remote cache, so most of that still applies).

You should start with [Ensure re-running the same build/test command produces cache hits](https://bazel.build/remote/cache-remote#rerun-cache-hits). The basic procedure is to run two builds with `--execution_log_binary_file=/tmp/exec1.log` (use different files each time) and then run a tool from the [bazel repository](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel):

```bash
bazel build src/tools/execlog:parser
bazel-bin/src/tools/execlog/parser \
  --log_path=/tmp/exec1.log \
  --log_path=/tmp/exec2.log \
  --output_path=/tmp/exec1.log.txt \
  --output_path=/tmp/exec2.log.txt
```

Then you can diff the resulting text files to see how the cache keys differ, which is why Bazel isn't resusing the cached results.

I recommend starting with a build of a small subset of the code you're building. Most reasons for cache misses will affect everything, and it makes iteration much faster.